# Camel Routes - How to return the body response as xml

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

First of all, I am new with Spring Boot.
I am not sure if it is possible, but I would like to return the xml response from the external url.

I have this code:

```
@GetMapping("/myPage")
public void myPage() {
    restConfiguration().host("localhost").port(8080);
    from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&delay=0")
            .to("rest:get:/external-page")
            .to("stream:out");
}
```

**myPage() is** returning a XML (that's OK). So, now I would like to return the same XML when I do:

```
curl http://localhost/myPage
```

I am not sure if I have to use **.to("stream:out")**, but the curl is returning an empty result.

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, this is how to get the response.

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            restConfiguration().host(sHost).port(iPort);
            from("direct:start")
                    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,simple("GET"))
                    .to("rest:get:/external-page");
        }
    });

    context.start();

    ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    String headerValue = "application/xml";

    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", headerValue);

    Object result = template.requestBodyAndHeaders("direct:start", null, headers, String.class);
    Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(context);
    String response = ExchangeHelper.convertToType(exchange, String.class, result);
    context.stop();

    return response;
```